# Why isn't viewWillDisappear or viewDidAppear being called?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` with a `UITableView` as my main menu. User clicks on a cell and a new view is pushed on the stack. In one case I push another `UITableView` that needs a toolbar. So on that 2nd tableView's init I setup the `self.toolbarItems` property with the correct items. But then I need to call `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];` So it makes sense to call this in the `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` method. But I put it in those methods and find out (Also via NSLog) that they never get called. The same goes for hiding it in `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`. Why don't these methods get called? Where should I be doing this hiding/showing of the toolbar then?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have noticed behavior where if a parent controller (like `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController`) never get's `viewWill/DidAppear` called on it, it won't call it on the child controllers either.  So make sure that in the code where you create the parent controller, you call `viewWillAppear`, show it, then call `viewDidAppear`.  Then it should make those calls on it's child controllers as is appropriate.

Double check the parent controller is having those methods called, and call them yourself if they are not.

Comment: Actually, you might also check if you're running on iOS5 - i've noticed that unlike iOS4 viewDidAppear:animated is being called there for a UIViewController that has a parentViewController without any additional setup

Answer (score 4):

Yes Its true

you can do this by first write this code in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.navigationController.delegate = self;  
}
```

And then write the code which you want to write in viewWillAppear

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController  *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController  *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {

    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {
        //write your code here
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you solved your problem, in case someone comes along in the future another problem could have been that you forgot the animated: argument to either method - that is to say, the format of the method needs to look like:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 0):

i noticed the same issue in iOS7. When i'm using both tab bar (2 buttons A, B) and navigation controller.

A has two views. One with tableview and second displays data according to the selection from the table view.

B has is the only view.

Button which is refer to another separate view D, placed in both tab bar views (A & B) and  in both views of A.

Problem arises when i click the button from tab item B, `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad` not called.

So i solved this issue by `presentModalViewController:animated:` and to come back i used `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`, just when i go to view D from tab item B.